# Sending an SMS message using Python; Time delay considering timezone

Tags: python, timezone

So I have a code that receives relevant information for a mobile device, such as phone number, name, and message, through which it can send an SMS message. Also, there is a function which delays the SMS. So a user can choose to send a message at a later time using a drop-down menu. Furthermore the delay function checks whether the time at which the message is to be sent between 12:00am to 8:00am, and if so then the default of 8:00am is returned so the receiver will get the message at 8:00am at the earliest. However the problem I am facing is that the time delay is in terms of Mountain Daylight Time (Canada/US), which means that people living in the PDT timezone will receive the message at 7:00am (hour too early) while people in EDT receive the message at 10:00am (2 hours too late). So I was wondering if there is some python code that would potentially detect which timezone the receiver is located in so that he/she receives the message on time (if I select 8:00am in Nevada then the receiver in California will receive the message at 8:00am PDT), given the area in which the receiver is located (eg. the code is given that the receiver is located in California).

Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick and Dirty**: You could dodge the problem by getting the user to say after how many hours/minutes the event should occur.  Then it doesn't matter what their local time zone is.

**Better**: If you have the ability to get the local time on the phone, as well as the UTC time (either from the phone or from your server), that will tell you the **UTC offset** of the phone.  You can get away with that most of the time.  But UTC offset is NOT the same thing as a local time zone.  Near a daylight-savings or summer-time boundary, ideas like "the same time tomorrow" break when you assume that the UTC offset is the same as the time zone.

**Best**: For supporting political time zone policies correctly, there is no substitute for the [Olson database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  Using Olson would imply that your app has a configuration item for the user to set their timezone (examples: `America/New_York` and `Etc/UTC`).  You might choose defaults for this based on the UTC offset of the phone and the mobile number (using lookup tables as detailed in the other answers) and be correct most of the time.

In Python the [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) module gives you a very clean API for using the Olson database to work with `datetime` objects.

EDIT: This function will convert Unix time to a localized `datetime` object, given a timezone object:

```
def localize_epoch_time(epoch_time, timezone=pytz.UTC):
  u"Given an epoch time return an accurate, timezone-aware datetime object"
  t = localtime(epoch_time)
  epochdt = datetime(*(t[:6] + (int((epoch_time - long(epoch_time)) * 1000000), timezone)
  if hasattr(timezone, 'normalize'):  # pytz tzinfo objects have this
    return timezone.normalize(epochdt)
  else: # tzinfo object not from pytz module
    return epochdt
```

Comment: Here is how the time is being sent into the function:

 `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", localtime(c.edt)) `

where `c.edt = int(time())`

I'm assuming `int(time())` is the MDT being sent in?

Now using the pytz module, how would I ensure that c.edt will always be the right time given the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

To accurately know the time zone of the owner of the phone is impossible unless you have some code of yours running on his phone as the owner of the phone could be travelling across time zones.

To address this concern you can do one of two things....

Best Guess: This is, use a reverse phone lookup API, like see http://www.phonenumber.com/phone/1-214-213-1234 It clearly tells you that the number belongs to Texasm hence the best guess would be use the texas time zone, its not always accurate but it is majority of the times. You need to hunt for APIs based on your usage.

Play Safe: Make sure that you may deliver in a time which is not extreme in any time zone, so that no one is disturbed. Hence lets say you pick 8:30 AM central time. Thats 6:30 AM pacific, and 9:30 AM eastern, so its not too early or too late in any time zone.

Answer (score 0):

With timezones, it's best to both guess and ask, because unless you have a GPS-like device you'll probably guess wrong.  And guessing is not an easy task, but worth it to improve your users' experience.

Are the messages being scheduled from a phone via SMS or from the web?  If from the phone, use a [phone lookup API](http://www.phonenumber.com/phone/1-214-213-1234) like @Adithya suggests.  If from the web, try a geo-ip service like http://www.hostip.info/ .  Then you'll need to find a service that converts geo coordinates to timezones.  I don't know of any off the top of my head, but I'm sure you can find some by googling.

Also keep in mind that IP addresses of mobile phones are notoriously difficult to geo-locate.  If it's a web interface being used from the phone, I probably wouldn't even bother with that route.  Try [HTML5 geo-location](http://html5demos.com/geo).

Comment: It's being scheduled from the web. Also, the delay function would be given the area in which the receiver resides (and will remain in this area). So instead of trying to geo-locate a mobile phone, we can probably determine the timezone-shifting through the area itself? Maybe I can try to use some mapping tool to figure that out. But thanks a lot for your comment, really helps!